# Unable to show the contents of the second table in Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I am using Linq to join 2 tables. I am able to get the contents of the first table but getting the second table as null. How can I extract the contents of the second table also into a single JSON object. My code is below:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Tbl_Students> GetAllStudents()
    {
        StudentDBEntities dataContext = new StudentDBEntities();

        var query = (from student in dataContext.Tbl_Students
                     join subject in dataContext.Tbl_Subjects on student.Roll_Number equals subject.Roll_Number
                     select new 
                     {
                         Roll_Number = student.Roll_Number,
                         FirstName = student.FirstName,
                         LastName = student.LastName,
                         Class = student.Class,
                         Gender = student.Gender,
                         Science = subject.Science,
                         Social = subject.Social,
                         Mathematics = subject.Mathematics,
                         Total = subject.Total
                     }).ToList().Select(s => new Tbl_Students
                     {
                         Roll_Number = s.Roll_Number,
                         FirstName = s.FirstName,
                         LastName = s.LastName,
                         Class = s.Class,
                         Gender = s.Gender
                     });



        return query;
    }
```

The two table structures are:

Student

```
public class Student
{
    public int Roll_Number { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Class { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Subject

```
class Subject
{
    public int Roll_Number { get; set; }
    public int Science { get; set; }
    public int Social { get; set; }
    public int Mathematics { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }


}
```

I am getting everything except the subjects in Fiddler.

Adding the image

[image]

Comment: But you are converting the results of the query to an enumerable of Tbl_Students yourself without specifying subjects. Do you expect it to fill the one-to-many relation automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are never populating Tbl_Subjects from your query. I have updated your query to populate Tbl_Subjects.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tbl_Students> GetAllStudents()
{
    StudentDBEntities dataContext = new StudentDBEntities();

    var query = (from student in dataContext.Tbl_Students
                 join subject in dataContext.Tbl_Subjects on student.Roll_Number equals subject.Roll_Number
                 select new 
                 {
                     Roll_Number = student.Roll_Number,
                     FirstName = student.FirstName,
                     LastName = student.LastName,
                     Class = student.Class,
                     Gender = student.Gender,
                     Science = subject.Science,
                     Social = subject.Social,
                     Mathematics = subject.Mathematics,
                     Total = subject.Total
                 }).ToList().Select(s => new Tbl_Students
                 {
                     Roll_Number = s.Roll_Number,
                     FirstName = s.FirstName,
                     LastName = s.LastName,
                     Class = s.Class,
                     Gender = s.Gender,
                     Tbl_Subjects = new Tbl_Subjects ()
                     {
                          Science = s.Science,
                          Social = s.Social,
                          Mathematics = s.Mathematics,
                          Total = s.Total
                           Roll_Number = s.Roll_Number
                     };
                 });



    return query;
}
```

Comment: A very silly mistake on my part. Thanks for the headsup @user1672994. Its working now.